# Nivoslider doesn't load on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, stack, nivo-slider

We're using NivoSlider on our website (www.senia.ro) and it doesn't load on iPad. It works on Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari on iPhone but it stacks images and <'li> on top of each other on iPad. 
I have tried to set width and height values but it still doesn't load. Is it a compatibility issue?

Comment: demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-lightbox/ Most of the links on their demo are broken on iOS 7 devices. I have no iOS 6 devices to test on however. I'm interested in this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, this thread helped me out:
https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Lightbox/issues/3

It looks like iOS doesn't like the transitions Nivo Lightbox was using. Try either updating your lightbox source files (it says the issue is fixed now in v1.1, or go into your nivo-lightbox.css file and comment out line 206:

```
/*-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;*/
```